# Collecting usage data for a desktop application

Tags: python, windows, usability, analytics, metrics

I'm going to be running some large scale usability tests of my software for a science project. We have a lab of about 30 computers running Windows XP. Our application is written in [Python](http://python.org) and [PyGTK](http://pygtk.org).

We want to be able to collect the following without staff intervention (automatically on our application start):

- A recording of the user session (a la [GtkRecordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sf.net))
- All tracebacks and errors produced by our application
- Amount of time till the user reaches a certain point in the application.
- A short survey presented at application exit

I think the last point is pretty straightforward, and I know how I'd store the data, but I don't know how I'd implement the other points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first point, I believe you can drive [recordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) directly from your Python code pretty easily -- I haven't done so, myself, but the docs make it look easy (and both existing frontends to it are in Python).

For your second point, set [sys.excepthook](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=excepthook#sys.excepthook) to intercept the exceptions and prepare your report via the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html?highlight=traceback#module-traceback) module.

For your third point, register the time at start (e.g. via [datetime.datetime.now](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.datetime#datetime.datetime.now)) and again at the point you care about, and log the difference.